# Have find show backslashes

Tags: linux, find

So if I do a find I get something like `./foo bar` but I want to get `./foo\ bar` and I know I can just look for each space but there are some other characters that have the same thing like `./[foo] bar` should be `./\[foo\]\ bar`.

Comment: Escaping paths for the shell is a pain; don't do it.  Instead, used `find ... -print0` to distinguish filenames.  If you really insist on escaping the strings, try: `find foo -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'printf "%q\n" "$@"' _ `

Answer (score 0):

Will was right

```
find foo -print0 | xargs -0 bash -c 'printf "%q\n" "$@"'
```